# MinGW 64 Bit Install trouble

Tags: c, installation, mingw, windows-7-x64

Hello i am trying to install the 64 bit compiler of MinGW so that i can program in c 64 bit but am not sure exactly how to accomplish this. I have download the 64 bit zip file and extracted it to the folder i want but am not sure how to get the compiler to work. My command line still seems to recognize the program i am using as 64 bit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your host platform - 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step by step instructions:

1) Download and extract mingw package from [mingw-builds](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/):

- [GCC 4.7 for 32bit host OS - i686 and x86-64 targets](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/detail?name=i686-mingw32-gcc-4.7.0-release-c,c%2b%2b,fortran-sjlj.zip&can=2&q=)
- [GCC 4.7 for 64bit host OS - i686 and x86-64 targets](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/detail?name=x86_64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.0-release-c,c%2b%2b,fortran-sjlj.zip&can=2&q=)

(actually first one should work fine on both host platforms)

2) Lets say the target directory was c:\mingw

Copy the code below to the test.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    printf("sizeof(void*)=%d bytes\n", sizeof(void*));
    return 0;
}
```

3) Compile 32 bit target:

```
c:\mingw\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe -m32 -o test.exe test.cpp
OR
c:\mingw\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe -m32 -o test.exe test.cpp
```

4) Compile 64 bit target:

```
c:\mingw\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe -m64 -o test.exe test.cpp
OR
c:\mingw\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe -m64 -o test.exe test.cpp
```

Comment: Note: mingw-builds moved from https://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/ to http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/.

Comment: An alternative to compiling it yourself would be to just install TDM-GCC. (The standard MinGW-based "TDM" edition or the MingW-w64-based "TDM64" edition.)